# Cбор статистики по загрузке процессора

Tags: linux, windows, администрирование

Как собрать статистику по загрузке процессора, памяти  процессами за промежуток времени,  в файл (Linux/Windows)?

Comment: Рекомендую задавать два разных вопроса про разные ОС, в решениях будет мало общего.

Answer (score 1):

Для Linux существуют инструменты мониторинга - Zabbix, Nagios и так далее. В них есть модули сбора и архивации статистики.